# What happens when you roll "Off the top" of a result table?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

For example, on the Pegasus' various weapon stations, there is a result chart printed on the board.  It covers the possibilities of getting a die result of 1-8, on an 8-sided die.  But now suppose someone had played a Strategic Planning or Calculations card, adding +2 or +1 to the die roll, such that the die comes up a 9 or a 10.  What is the result?  The chart does not seem to cover this situation.  A similar situation arises on New Caprica with the human vs Cylon conflict rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has now officially been answered in the latest [FAQ](http://fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_1-1-3-new.pdf):

> Q: Can the result of a die roll be modified to be more than an 
>   “8”?
>
> A: No. After all modifications to a die roll have been calculated, 
>   any number greater than an “8” is treated as an “8.”

Comment: Why not add this to your approved answer above?

Comment: @Pat I questioned the appropriateness of that. Appending it to the original answer didn't seem quite right, because it kind of makes the whole answer moot (My speculation is now irrelevant as an official answer has been given, and it does contradict my answer in that the result should not be greater than 8, it should be 8.) Replacing my original answer with this didn't seem quite right either as it is a different answer. Dunno, what do you think?

Comment: I've thrown it up for discussion on [meta](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-to-do-when-an-answer-is-no-longer-correct).

Comment: I switched the accepted answer to this one, since its more chapter-and-verse, and since its the same guy's answer, it has no reputation consequences :)

Answer (score 1):

Treat any result higher than an 8 as an 8.

Comment: Do you know if there's any official guidance on this, or is this just the 'standard' house rule to cover an ambiguous situation?

Comment: Standard house rules.  I can't think of any alternative that would be rational other than treating the top of the list as the best possible result.  It is kind of like dealing with partial success skill checks: if you meet the top number you get the best result.

Comment: The actual issue arose in response to a 'covert' cylon player using calculations to boost the die roll over the chart.  The logic was "there's no result for a 9, so the roll has no result".  We're establishing a house rule for next game, but it'd have been nice to have some rule documentation "on point".

Answer (score 1):

Looked through the rules and found nothing on point.

However, at the [BSG Forums](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_temas.asp?efid=24&efcid=1), it is commonplace to see folks treating a roll higher than 8 as an 8.  There doesn't appear to be any dissent.  I didn't see anyone disagreeing or challenging that assertion.

Here is one [example](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_discusion.asp?efid=24&efcid=1&efidt=327390&efpag=0#329567):

> Save nukes for when you really need them. Don't be afraid of throwing out a strategic planning card to thin some Raiders out too if possible.